# Payment gateway with Python SDK compatible with GAE

Tags: python, google-app-engine, payment-gateway

I'm looking for a Payment gateway that offers Python SDK which would run on GAE. So far I've looked at Braintree[1] and TrustCommerce[2], and both required C-based libraries to work, which won't work on GAE. If there's no such thing, which payment gateway would you recommend that provides a possibly JSON-based API or a nice RESTful API.

[1] http://www.braintreepayments.com/
[2] http://www.trustcommerce.com/

Braintree uses PycURL library which is C-based
TrustCommerce comes with some C files that need to be compiled during install

EDIT: 
I'll vote close on this, because it's been suggested that such thing is impossible because URLfetch has a 10 second limit which is not sufficient in this case. For those interested, it has been suggested to me that using a proxy for payment processing would be better.

Answer (score 0):

It would be really helpful if you provided links. I googled and found this [TrustCommerce](http://www.trustcommerce.com/code-tools/api-sdk), but I guess maybe it's a different company to the one you are talking about because they say there is sample Python code.

I didn't sign up for a trial account just to see if the Python API requires a C library. Afterall maybe it's not even the same TrustCommerce you have looked at.

This isn't really the right site to do your research, you should come back and ask for help if you have problems using the API when you have found/chosen one.